# How to send constantly updated data in http request?

Tags: python, multithreading, http, operating-system, communication

Let assume I have computer A and a variable x which updated very frequently, and also takes some time for this update( Lets say: asked to be updated every sec and update tooks 0.5 sec).

Now, once a minute, I have computer B which asks in a HTTP GET request for x's value. A sends him a copy of x.

Because x might be used by A, I need to make sure that nothing gets wrong.

How can I assure it? What are my options for doing this?

Comment: I don't think I quite understand your question but are you looking for something like this:

Have a variable "busy" and set it to true if "x" is being used. So if if A is using "X" and B sends an HTTP GET request, the server will respond that "x" is in use or reject the request.

Comment: @farooqaaa I cant reject the request, I must return x or function on x.
How can I wait in a smart way for A to finish using x?

Comment: remember last `x` and send it without waiting for new `x`

Comment: If it's constantly updated then just give it the current value of "x". The next time it requests it should get the new value. If the value of "x" is used it doesn't mean that it cannot be accessed.

The same goes if you reject the request when busy. The next request will retrieve the new value.

Comment: @furas and what if A is accessing last x for update and B is asking him, in the same time...

Comment: remember last `x` (as copy) in separated variable - and use this copy to send to B

Comment: @furas but what if A is updating last x exactly at the time where B asks him? What if I can't keep last x, its too much for me?

Comment: @farooqaaa can you explain again?

Comment: Before A start updating it has to create copy.

Comment: @member555 I think you are focusing too much on theory before writing any code. You should write some code, run some tests and see how it turns out. Or if you already have code then show us the code you are using.

Comment: @farooqaaa that's the worst advice you can give someone writing concurrent code. Tests can never prove that code is correct just that it's faulty. And testing concurrent code is notoriously hard to begin with, much better to consider the problems beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can return x in function callback.

or like twisted reactor.callLater, server B could ask twice waiting for A get lasted result. but x update per-second, i may lead to other servers always request。